# How to show only Hours and days selectors?

Tags: wpf, datetime, datetimepicker

In my application, I need to show to the user just day on week selector and hours selector. the date is not relevant at all. I try to use `DateTimePicker` but I don't find a way to remove the calendar.

I new on `WPF` so I hope my question is not silly...
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you have to create a custom style for DateTimePicker to show just what you want. As an alternative, you could use another UserControl like this one [DateTimePicker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker)

Comment: Thank a lot' i try it.
but the [DataTimePicker](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpftoolkit)  is "contains harmful programs"